# Realm Population breakdown

Tags: world-of-warcraft

When looking at the Realm List, you can see 4 different types of Population Status:

1. Full
2. Medium
3. Low
4. New Players

What determines each status? Is it only the players currently actively on the realm? Are there any other things influencing this?

Comment: Not seeing how this is getting off-topic votes. Questions asking for what numbers make things reach different thresholds in games are very much on topic here. Nothing in this is asking why the devs chose the numbers/etc.

Comment: @BillyMailman Well yes the question seems on-topic but after some research you'll find that exact numbers are kept secret by blizzard and that they are [unknown to the community](http://www.wowwiki.com/Population). I really like the question but it's not answerable just by playing the game, since there is no method of counting all the players online (or at least not one that wouldn't be too broad here). I'll gladly retract my CV if the question doesn't ask for Numbers.

Comment: Whether or not anyone happens to know the answer isn't generally a reason to close a particular question. Kinda means the asker would need to already know the answer before asking, to be sure they were on-topic.

Comment: A lot of what is being asked here isn't really answerable.  It requires knowledge that is unable to be found, nor tested for.  Adding other information that might be in the formula pushes it well outside our scope.

Comment: The comment of @Jutschge is kind of the answer to this question then. I do not think this question to be off-topic or too broad. It is a question and answer website, and this is a valid question within the specified parameters within the Tour page.

Comment: Anyway, the fact that we cannot know the exact number, but that it is only influenced by the amount of players currently logged in - that would be a perfect answer, if it is correct.

Comment: @HowlinWulf Well as I said, If you take out the number Part I'm gonna vote for a reopen since It's answerable by playing the game. The main problem Is that the exact numbers are only known by Blizzard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've already more or less described this in my [first comment](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/183467/realm-population-breakdown#comment248536_183467).

The exact method used by Blizzard to determine the status is [currently unknown](http://www.wowwiki.com/Population), however through personal observations and some research I found out that the server population status is determined by **Players that are currently online**.

You will often find servers that have a medium population during the day and a low one during the night around 4-5 am (I've personally played on one of these) and it's highly unlikely that every night people delete a lot of characters.

The main problem with finding the exact method is that the `/who` command will only show you up to 50 players and it's basically impossible to count all the players that are online (maybe it would work for the statuses "New Players" and "Low").

If you want additional information to a servers population, you can visit [Realmpop](http://wow.realmpop.com/) which has a really nice overview about all the servers in EU and NA.